# Listen to Changes on FutureProvider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I've been trying to find some good examples on how to **rebuild** a `ListView.builder` while using the `FutureProvider`. My goal is to have a search function where I can query into `SQFlite` and return a new list that will be reassigned to the `ListView.builder`. My code is working fine but it seems like I'm having a bad luck in rebuilding the UI in `FutureProvider`. what am I missing?

**main.dart**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        FutureProvider<List<BillingData>>(
          create: (context) => BillingDataService().getBillingData(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(),
    );
  }
}
```

**billing_data_service.dart**

```
  Future<List<BillingData>> getBillingData() async{
    var dbClient = await locator.get<SQLService>().getDatabase;
    var billingData = await dbClient.rawQuery(//some query here);
    
    return billingData.map((e) => BillingData.fromDB(e)).toList();
  }


  Future<List<BillingData>> searchConcessionaire(String value) async{
    var dbClient = await locator.get<SQLService>().getDatabase;
    var searchResult = await dbClient.rawQuery(//some search query);

    return searchResult.map((e) => BillingData.fromDB(e)).toList();
  }
```

**concessionaire_screen.dart**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  List<BillingData> billingData = Provider.of<List<BillingData>>(context);
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: (billingData == null)
              ? Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
              : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: billingData.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ConcessionaireCard(
                    index: index,
                    fullName: billingData[index].fullName,
                    ctName: billingData[index].ctName,
                    mtrNo: billingData[index].mtrNo,
                    prevReading: billingData[index].prevReading,
                    curReading: billingData[index].curReading,
                );
              }),
        ,
      );
}
```

Comment: since you want multiple events to be emitted, then  you need [StreamProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html), not `FutureProvider`

Comment: So ive been trying to look into stream providers and it looks like my database instance returns a future.

Comment: check https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#modify-stream-methods and find keyword  `asyncMap`